# Create and Save XML file to Server Using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm using PHP to extract data from a MySQL database. I am able to build an XML file using  DOM functions. Then using  `echo $dom->saveXML();` , I am able to return the XML from an AJAX call. Instead of using AJAX to get the XML, how would I save the XML file to a spot on the server? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`DOMDocument::save()` method](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) to save the XML document into a file:

```
$dom->save('document.xml');
```

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't [DOMDocument::save()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) help you?

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP XML DOM Parser to create and save XML file. The following code and tutorial would be found from here - [Create and Save XML File using PHP](http://www.codexworld.com/create-save-xml-file-using-php/)

```
$xmlString = 'Insert XML Content';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($xmlString);

$dom->save('fileName.xml');
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides "save" option of the DOM itself stated by two previous ansers, you could also use this piece of code:

```
$strxml = $dom->saveXML();
$handle = fopen("yourxmlfile.xml", "w");
fwrite($handle, $strxml);
fclose($handle);
```

And you are done.

Remember that the user running your application server (Apache, probably) will need permissions to write in the directory you are placing the XML file.